# How do I get a list of class dependencies in a Python module using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I want to check the dependencies of multiple classes in some module.

To be on the same page, as far as the concept is concerned, an object (A) is dependent on another object (B) if any change in B can affect A. This is what I know and read across different OOP mediums. However, none addressed Python's dependencies.

I am familiar with drawing out inheritance from a Python source code but I don't know anything about dependencies.

I tried reading from several sources but all I got was [Dependency injection in Python](https://medium.com/@shivama205/dependency-injection-python-cb2b5f336dce), none about referencing to the core OOP concept.

I also read a [blog post](https://coderwall.com/p/mvjw9a/recursively-finding-dependencies-in-python) but it hardly reflected any OOP concept to me.

Comment: How are the dependencies reflected in the class fields?

Comment: I am sorry, but I have no idea. Could you layout a general example to start with? By `some module` in my question, I meant that I am designing a program that would list out dependencies in any module.